# Certificate with thumbprint 099822424207A0CF4EB1882413CxxxxxD3 not found

Tags: asp.net, azure, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault, .net-6.0

I am developing a Web API using docker to be hosted on Azure. And I'm trying to use Azure key vault(follow this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b21EQvfjvHc)). But I got an error when I deployed

> Certificate with thumbprint 099822424207A0CF4EB1882xxxxxxxD3 not found

Although I have added the certificate to azure [image]

I also tried adding this to my .csprj file

```
<ApplicationManifest>certificate.pem</ApplicationManifest>
<PackageCertificateThumbprint>099822424207A0CF4EB1882xxxxxxD3</PackageCertificateThumbprint>
```

But not thing work

What could be going wrong here? Tks for your time